# Copy similar nodes from multiple XML files to one XML using excel VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, merge, nodes

I have to generate several xml files throughout the day as request flows in. The following are the two sample files which are similar to the files I generate

Sample 1

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <BRCDATA>
   <FILENAME>BSID000001016032012001</FILENAME>
   <ENVELOPE>
     <EBRC>
       <BRCNO>BSID0000010000001001</BRCNO>
       <BRCDATE>2011-03-15</BRCDATE>
       <STATUS>F</STATUS>
       <IEC>1234567890</IEC>
       <NAME>BINAYAKTEX PROCESSORS LTD.</NAME>
       <IFSC>BSID0000010</IFSC>
       <BILLID>000000000001AM12</BILLID>
       <SNO>6995678</SNO>
       <SPORT>INBOM4</SPORT>
       <SDATE>2020-11-02</SDATE>
       <SCC>USD</SCC>
       <SVALUE>1439075.66</SVALUE>
       <RCC>USD</RCC>
       <RVALUE>1438995.66</RVALUE>
       <RDATE>2021-03-02</RDATE>
     </EBRC>
   </ENVELOPE>
 </BRCDATA>
```

Sample 2:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <BRCDATA>
   <FILENAME>BSID000001016032012001</FILENAME>
   <ENVELOPE>
     <EBRC>
       <BRCNO>BSID0000010000001001</BRCNO>
       <BRCDATE>2011-03-15</BRCDATE>
       <STATUS>F</STATUS>
       <IEC>7980123456</IEC>
       <NAME>VARDHAMAN MILLS LTD.</NAME>
       <IFSC>BSID000100</IFSC>
       <BILLID>000000000001AM14</BILLID>
       <SNO>6978956</SNO>
       <SPORT>INBLR4</SPORT>
       <SDATE>2020-10-12</SDATE>
       <SCC>USD</SCC>
       <SVALUE>39055.00</SVALUE>
       <RCC>USD</RCC>
       <RVALUE>39025.00</RVALUE>
       <RDATE>2021-03-01</RDATE>
     </EBRC>
   </ENVELOPE>
 </BRCDATA>
```

At the end of the day I need to merge all the `<EBRC>` nodes from all such XML files generated in the day, into just one XML file, before I upload the same in our system. Like the one below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <BRCDATA>
   <FILENAME>BSID000001016032012001</FILENAME>
   <ENVELOPE>
     <EBRC>
       <BRCNO>BSID0000010000001001</BRCNO>
       <BRCDATE>2011-03-15</BRCDATE>
       <STATUS>F</STATUS>
       <IEC>1234567890</IEC>
       <NAME>BINAYAKTEX PROCESSORS LTD.</NAME>
       <IFSC>BSID0000010</IFSC>
       <BILLID>000000000001AM12</BILLID>
       <SNO>6995678</SNO>
       <SPORT>INBOM4</SPORT>
       <SDATE>2020-11-02</SDATE>
       <SCC>USD</SCC>
       <SVALUE>1439075.66</SVALUE>
       <RCC>USD</RCC>
       <RVALUE>1438995.66</RVALUE>
       <RDATE>2021-03-02</RDATE>
     </EBRC>
     <EBRC>
       <BRCNO>BSID0000010000001001</BRCNO>
       <BRCDATE>2011-03-15</BRCDATE>
       <STATUS>F</STATUS>
       <IEC>7980123456</IEC>
       <NAME>VARDHAMAN MILLS LTD.</NAME>
       <IFSC>BSID000100</IFSC>
       <BILLID>000000000001AM14</BILLID>
       <SNO>6978956</SNO>
       <SPORT>INBLR4</SPORT>
       <SDATE>2020-10-12</SDATE>
       <SCC>USD</SCC>
       <SVALUE>39055.00</SVALUE>
       <RCC>USD</RCC>
       <RVALUE>39025.00</RVALUE>
       <RDATE>2021-03-01</RDATE>
     </EBRC>
   </ENVELOPE>
 </BRCDATA>
```

I tried using the following lines of code in excel VBA, but I am unable to get the merged `<EBRC>` nodes from various XML to one xml file. Pls help.

```
   Sub OpenSeveralFiles()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileChosen As Integer
Dim FileName As String, NewXMLFile As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim docXMLDOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim nodRoot As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim lstVideos As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim lstVideos1 As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim xmlFileName As String
Dim XML As Object, FSO As Object
    
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set XML = FSO.CreateTextFile(FileName:="C:\VBA Projectroom\XML MERGE\COPY1\new_combined.xml", Overwrite:=True)

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'use the standard title and filters, but change the
'initial folder

fd.InitialFileName = "C:\VBA Projectroom\XML MERGE\COPY1"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList

'allow multiple file selection

fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
FileChosen = fd.Show

If FileChosen = -1 Then

'open each of the files chosen
Set docXMLDOM = New DOMDocument

For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count

xmlFileName = fd.SelectedItems(i)
docXMLDOM.Load (xmlFileName)

Set nodRoot = docXMLDOM.DocumentElement
Set lstVideos = nodRoot.getElementsByTagName("EBRC")
    
MsgBox lstVideos(0).XML
docXMLDOM.Load "C:\VBA Projectroom\XML MERGE\COPY1\new_combined.xml"
docXMLDOM.appendChild (lstVideos(0))

Next i
End If
Set docXMLDOM = Nothing
Set XML = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can someone help me complete the code. I am not able to debug the code. Pls help.
I need the script/codes in EXCEL VBA as MS excel is the only program that our organization has installed on our office systems and allows us to work on MS EXCEL. Running Excel Macros are allowed. We cannot run any other .exe files without alerting our IT ADMIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the first file and then append to the ENVELOPE node the EBRC nodes from the others.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenSeveralFiles()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\VBA Projectroom\XML MERGE\COPY1\"
    Const OUTFILE = "new_combined.xml"

    Dim fd As FileDialog, FSO As Object, FileChosen As Integer
    Dim xmlFileName As String
   
    Dim docOut As DOMDocument, docIn As DOMDocument
    Dim node As IXMLDOMElement, env As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim i As Integer
     
    ' select files to merge
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .InitialFileName = FOLDER
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        FileChosen = fd.Show
    End With

    If FileChosen <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set docOut = New DOMDocument
    Set docIn = New DOMDocument

    'open each of the files chosen
    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        xmlFileName = fd.SelectedItems(i)
        'Debug.Print xmlFileName

        If i = 1 Then
            ' first file load complete
            docOut.Load xmlFileName
            Set env = docOut.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("ENVELOPE")(0)
        Else
            ' other files append to envelope
            docIn.Load xmlFileName
            Set node = docIn.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("EBRC")(0)
            env.appendChild node
        End If
    Next i
    docOut.Save FOLDER & OUTFILE
    MsgBox i - 1 & " files merged to " & OUTFILE, vbInformation, "Path: " & FOLDER
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @OmkarK If you are happy please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)