# Edit XML with Excel VBA (or PowerShell) - copy all tag values in node to a different node

Tags: excel, xml, vba, powershell, xsd

I have an XML file (well 35 actually) which configure my system. The system has recently had an upgrade, and some of the equivalent paths have moved (various reasons, file size efficiency mainly). I'm looking for a way to map values from the old XML into the new (created from the new template XML). This isn't a one-off, I'll be giving this to the customer to remap hundreds of configs; and I'm expecting perhaps a thousand tags to either copy or remap per config.

```
<AW tagdbtype="Node">
  <BS number="201" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""/>
    <Tag alias="PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled</Tag>
    <Value tagdbtype="DigitalTag"/>
    <Action maxValue="2147483647" minValue="-2147483648" tagdbtype="IntegerTag"/>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
    <OffAction tagdbtype="AttributeInteger" value="2">2</OffAction>
    <OnAction tagdbtype="AttributeInteger" value="2">2</OnAction>
  </BS>
  <BS number="202" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""/>
    <Tag alias="PC.MxOff.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.MxOff.Enabled</Tag>
    <Value tagdbtype="DigitalTag"/>
    <Action maxValue="2147483647" minValue="-2147483648" tagdbtype="IntegerTag"/>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
    <OffAction tagdbtype="AttributeInteger" value="2">2</OffAction>
    <OnAction tagdbtype="AttributeInteger" value="2">2</OnAction>
  </BS>
  <BS number="203" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""/>
    <Tag alias="PC.MxOn.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.MxOn.Enabled</Tag>
    <Value tagdbtype="DigitalTag"/>
    <Action maxValue="2147483647" minValue="-2147483648" tagdbtype="IntegerTag"/>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
    <OffAction tagdbtype="AttributeInteger" value="2">2</OffAction>
    <OnAction tagdbtype="AttributeInteger" value="2">2</OnAction>
  </BS>
</AW>
```

I need to

- remap any attribute* tag or alias from node 201 to 31. There will be a list of remapping node pairs. There may also be instances where a single tag needs remapping.
- copy all of the other tags directly across
- don't modify any tags that are in the new template that didn't exist in the old configuration

e.g. The remapping table would look something like:

```
AW.BS._201.* -> AW.BS._31.*
AW.BS._202.* -> AW.BS._32.*
AW.RC._105.Enabled -> AW.RC._15.Enabled
```

Note that the node/path depth could vary from 2 to 9 for a particular map, so stacked loops will be messy.

I've been trying to follow along with several pages I've found on StackExchange, https://analystcave.com/vba-xml-working-xml-files/, a few others; I've used many different methods, but none are recognising the nodes or values properly.

Is the XML structure of attributes what is breaking it?

---

Here's my attempts so far:

**Attempt 1:**

```
Sub XML_Tag_Builder(SourceFile As String, SourceDescription As String, RowNr As Integer)
                   

Dim myVar As String, pathToXML As String
Dim XMLDOC As Object, xmlRoot As Object
    
    
    Set XMLDOC = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Call XMLDOC.Load(SourceFile)
    Set xmlRoot = XMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("*")
    
    For Each TagPath In xmlRoot

        Debug.Print "baseName = " & TagPath.BaseName
        Debug.Print "NodeTypeString = " & TagPath.nodeTypeString
        
        For Each TagAttribute In TagPath.Attributes
            Debug.Print "TagAttribute.name = " & TagAttribute.Name
            Debug.Print "TagAttribute.nodeValue = " & TagAttribute.NodeValue
        
        Next TagAttribute
    
    Next TagPath

End Sub
```

This appears to load the XML correctly, but I'm struggling to see how I can call a single tag or node by it's XML path, let alone copy everything in a node in one hit.

---

**Attempt 2:**

```
Sub XML_Tag_Builder(SourceFile As String)
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/28979225/2317071

    intFile = 2
    Open SourceFile For Input As intFile
    
    'Load XML into string strXML
    While Not EOF(intFile)
        Line Input #intFile, strXML
    Wend
    Close intFile
    
    Dim XMLDOC As Object
    Set objDOM = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Dim xmlNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    objDOM.LoadXML strXML
    XPath = "AW"
    Set xmlNode = objDOM.SelectNodes(XPath)
    Set oNodes = objDOM.getElementsByTagName("BS")
    If oNodes.Length > 0 Then
        For Each oNode In oNodes
            Debug.Print oNode.Number
            Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("Description").Text
            Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("Tag").Text
            Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("OffDelay").Text
            Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("OnDelay").Text
            Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("OffAction").Text
            Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("OnAction").Text
        Next oNode
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The whole xmlNode appears to load OK, and has a lot of child items which look to be populated correctly from my file; but oNodes is empty.

---

**Attempt 3:**

```
Sub XML_Tag_Builder(SourceFile As String)
' https://analystcave.com/vba-xml-working-xml-files/

    Dim XDoc As Object
    
    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XDoc.Load (SourceFile)
    
    Set listChildrenField = XDoc.SelectNodes("//AW/BS/Number[9]/*")
 
    Set XDoc = Nothing


End Sub
```

Again, XDoc loads and has a lot of child items, but listChildrenField is empty.

---

I also started poking around in PowerShell, but I can't see how to reference my nodes correctly yet. I find VBA easier to work with as I can step and have watches.

Thanks for your help!

---

**Update to clarify requirements:**

**Existing XML:**
(some tags removed for simplification):

```
<AW tagdbtype="Node">
  <OldTitle tagdbtype="AttributeString" value="SiteName">SiteName<OldTitle/>
  <BS number="201" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""/>
    <Tag alias="PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled</Tag>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
  </BS>
  <BS number="202" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""/>
    <Tag alias="PC.MxOff.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.MxOff.Enabled</Tag>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="10">10</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="10">10</OnDelay>
  </BS>
</AW>
```

**Template XML:**
AW.NewTitle, AW.BS._31 and AW.BS._32 all exist in the new template XML.

```
<AW tagdbtype="Node">
  <NewTitle tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""><NewTitle />
  <BS number="31" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value="BS--Job1"/>
    <Tag alias="" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag"></Tag>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
  </BS>
  <BS number="32" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value="BS--Job2"/>
    <Tag alias="" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag"></Tag>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
  </BS>
</AW>
```

**Remap job:**

- AW.BS._201.* -> AW.BS._31.*
- AW.BS._202.* -> AW.BS._32.*
- AW.OldTitle -> AW.NewTitle (Tag AW.NewTitle didn't exist in the old XML. Need to copy the value, not rename the tag.)

**Expected new XML:**

```
<AW tagdbtype="Node">
  <NewTitle tagdbtype="AttributeString" value="SiteName">SiteName<NewTitle/>
  <BS number="31" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value="BS--Job1"/>
    <Tag alias="PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled</Tag>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
  </BS>
  <BS number="32" tagdbtype="Node">
    <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value="BS--Job2"/>
    <Tag alias="PC.MxOff.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.MxOff.Enabled</Tag>
    <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="10">10</OffDelay>
    <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="10">10</OnDelay>
  </BS>
</AW>
```

*Ideally*, ignore certain tags - this would probably mean looping every tag by name. E.g. Old XML didn't have descriptions filled in, new template does.

---

**Update:** I have got XML Schema Definition (xsd) files for this XML, forgot I had it. I'm sure they'll help but haven't figured out how just yet.

Comment: Is there a default namespace declared in the XML file? It would be an xmlns declaration which doesn't declare any prefix, like this: `<foo xmlns="bar.bat.com">`

Comment: [Obtain attribute names from xml using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887820/obtain-attribute-names-from-xml-using-vba/51919182#51919182)?

Comment: What do you mean *remap*? *Directly across*? Where is the *template*? Please post desired output XML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696320/copy-similar-nodes-from-multiple-xml-files-to-one-xml-using-excel-vba has an example of copying nodes between XML documents

Comment: @Parfait - Remap = copy all the info from one node in the original file to a different numbered node in the new file. E.g. AW.BS._201.* -> AW.BS._31.*. Actually, a better description would be to populate the data in the new file node 31 with the data from the old file node 201.

Comment: Then the attribute values, `BS--Job1` and `BS--Job2` should be removed since they are not in 201?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a parmeterized [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Using the [MSXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms763742(v=vs.85)) library, VBA can run XSLT 1.0. For your use case, you can use the `document()` function to parse from an external file (relative directory to XSLT script) and even pass the list of remapping node pairs as parameters from Excel spreadsheet to XSLT script:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file; reads `Input.xml` at same level as .xsl script)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- INITIALIZE PARAMETERS -->
  <xsl:param name="old_number" />
  <xsl:param name="new_number" />
  
  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- ADJUST NewTitle NODE -->
  <xsl:template match="NewTitle">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Input.xml')/AW/OldTitle/@*|
                                   document('Input.xml')/AW/OldTitle/text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
  
  <!-- CONDITIONALLY ADJUST BS NODE -->
  <xsl:template match="BS">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:if test="@number = $old_number">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Input.xml')/AW/BS[@number=$new_number]/*"/>
      </xsl:if>
  
      <xsl:if test="@number != $old_number">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Spreadsheet**

[image: Spreadsheet Data]

**VBA** *(parses template XML and transforms it with Original XML)*

```vb
Sub Param_XSLT_Process()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' ADD REFERENCE Microsoft XML, v6.0
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument60
    Dim xslTemp As New MSXML2.XSLTemplate60
    Dim xslProc As Object

    Dim lLastRow As Long, lRow As Long

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmldoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Template.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.SetProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Stylesheet.xsl"

    ' INITIALIZE NEEDED OBJECTS
    Set xslTemp.stylesheet = xslDoc
    Set xslProc = xslTemp.createProcessor()

    xslProc.input = xmldoc

    ' ITERATE THROUGH EACH ROW, TRANSFORM, SAVE XML OUTPUT
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN")
       lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

       For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
           ' BIND PARAMETER(S)
           xslProc.addParameter "old_number", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value)    
           xslProc.addParameter "new_number", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)

           xslProc.transform                   ' TRANSFORM XML
           newDoc.LoadXML xslProc.output       ' LOAD RESULT TREE TO NEW XML
           xslProc.input = newDoc              ' RE-ASSIGN NEW XML INTO XSLT PROCEDURE
       Next lRow
    End With

    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"        ' SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
           
    MsgBox "Successfully processed XML files!", vbInformation

ExitHandle:
    Set xmldoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set xslTemp = Nothing: Set xslProc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise xslDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xslDoc.parseError.reason
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AW tagdbtype="Node">
    <NewTitle tagdbtype="AttributeString" value="SiteName">SiteName</NewTitle>
    <BS number="31" tagdbtype="Node">
        <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""></Description>
        <Tag alias="PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.WCO.T._1.Enabled</Tag>
        <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OffDelay>
        <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="0">0</OnDelay>
    </BS>
    <BS number="32" tagdbtype="Node">
        <Description tagdbtype="AttributeString" value=""></Description>
        <Tag alias="PC.MxOff.Enabled" reboot="true" tagdbtype="AliasTag">PC.MxOff.Enabled</Tag>
        <OffDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="10">10</OffDelay>
        <OnDelay precision="3" tagdbtype="AttributeFP" value="10">10</OnDelay>
    </BS>
</AW>
```